# Compute Perentages of Values in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not experienced in python and I have one last modification I need to make to a data set. My data looks like this:

```
"bone": {
    "SEV": 12, 
    "ER": 16, 
    "FAM": 177
}, 
"fracture": {
    "SEV": 76
}, 
"chest pain": {
    "ER": 6
},
```

It is a large number of keys, each with 1 to 10 or so labels. What I want to do is change the numbers to probabilities. So, for instance,

```
"bone": {
"SEV": .05, 
"ER": .07, 
"FAM": .86
},
```

So, sum up the total sum of tags and then divide each tag's value by the sum. I'm not sure how to iterate through these in an efficient way.

EDIT: Code I'm trying and not working

```
with open('probability.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

loadedd = json.loads(data)


def calculate_percentage(labels):
     total = float(sum(labels.values()))
     return {k: v / total for k,v in labels.items()}

for section in loadedd:
     section = calculate_percentage(section)
```

Gives the error

```
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: There don't appear to be any tuples in this code...

Comment: `data` is probably no string, that can be used with `json.loads`.

Comment: @Daniel , the data has tags that each have a decimal value.

Comment: Your document is not a valid json document - it has trailing comma. Drop it, after that you'll be able to load it to python dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'bone': {'SEV': 12, 
                 'ER': 16, 
                 'FAM': 177 
                }   
       }   


for injury, ward_dict in data.iteritems():

    total = float(sum(ward_dict.values()))
    percentage = [number / total for number in ward_dict.values()]
    data_out = {injury: {k: v for k, v in zip(ward_dict.keys(), percentage)} }
    print(data_out)
```

Which will print out a new dictionary with the percentages as the keys:

```
{'bone': {'SEV': 0.05853658536585366, 'ER': 0.07804878048780488, 'FAM': 0.8634146341463415}}
```

Comment: Great!  Also, minor typo above the the percentages are the values of the inner dictionary, not the keys.

Comment: Its all good, I was able to do everything I needed using your code as a template, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to sum the values and divide each item by this sum:

```
def calculate_percentage(labels):
    total = float(sum(labels.values()))
    return {k: v / total for k,v in labels.items()}

print calculate_percentage({
    "SEV": 12, 
    "ER": 16, 
    "FAM": 177
})
```

results in

```
{'SEV': 0.05853658536585366, 'ER': 0.07804878048780488, 'FAM': 0.8634146341463415}
```

Comment: total = float(sum(labels.values()))
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'. I guess I got my datastructure wrong

Comment: You have to convert your string to python dicts, e.g. with `json.loads`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I updated the question with the code I'm trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dictionary of dictionaries , something like -

```
dict = { 'a' : { 'SEV' : 12 , 'ER' : 6 } }
```

You can use something like -

```
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    vtot = sum(v.values())
    for k1,v1 in vtot.iteritems():
        vtot[k1] = v1 / vtot
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

Your document is not valid json document due to trailing comma. Valid document would look like this:

```
"bone": {
    "SEV": 12, 
    "ER": 16, 
    "FAM": 177
}, 
"fracture": {
    "SEV": 76
}, 
"chest pain": {
    "ER": 6
}
```

Also you are calling json library method twice, which is one to much. Simply one call is sufficient:

```
with open('probability.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
assert isinstance(data, dict)
```

After that you should be able to postprocess your data as following:

```
for section in data.keys():
     section_total = float(sum(data[section].itervalues()))
     data[section] =  {k: v / section_total for k,v in labels.iteritems()}
```